# Solving simultaneous linear congruences.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

I'm struggling when solving the simultaneous linear congruences $$x\equiv 3 \pmod{101^{1000}}$$ and $$x\equiv 3 \pmod{7^{200}}$$ where the moduli are very large. I haven't got an issue when solving more reasonably sized moduli.

Could I solve this by reducing them to $x\equiv 3 \pmod{101}$ and $x\equiv 3 \pmod7$? I did this and I got $x\equiv 3 \pmod{707}$ using the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Could I somehow use this result to be $mod7^{200}101^{1000}$ or have I approached this problem completely wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Chinese Remainder Theorem also works for coprime numbers. They need not to be primes.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, in this case the equation can be solved easily. Just use the fact that
$$101^{1000} \mid x-3$$
$$7^{200} \mid x-3 $$ 
Because $\text{gcd}(101^{1000},7^{200}) = 1$, these two equations are equivalent with
$$101^{1000}.7^{200} \mid x-3$$
So your solutions are all the numbers that bear this property.

Comment: I understand this. I knew this when asking the question. Isn't there a unique answer for the question? How would I go about finding it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I understand your question. The answer I gave gives a necessary and sufficient condition. Or what do you want to know?

Comment: I want to know x that satisfies both congruences. So isn't a number modulo $101^{1000}.7^{200}$